# The following program finds the correct answer if summation is done via loop but incorrect if done via formula for GP. Why?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

the following code is my solution to the problem : http://codeforces.com/contest/327/problem/C

The first part where I perform summation via loop (therefore having a bad time complexity) gives the correct answer.

The second part where I use formula of geometric progression returns incorrect answer for a lot of test cases even though I think the formula used is correct.

What am I doing wrong? (Edit:- Problem identified. Explained at the end)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
typedef long long int lli;

using namespace std;

lli power(lli base, lli exponent)
{
    lli result=1;
    while(exponent)
    {
        if(exponent & 1)
            result=(result*base)%1000000007;
        exponent>>=1;
        base=(base*base)%1000000007;
    }
    return result%1000000007;
}
int main()
{
    string n;
    cin>>n;
    lli k;
    cin>>k;
    vector<int> position;
    for(int i=0;i<n.length();i++)
        if(n[i]=='5' || n[i]=='0')
            position.push_back(i);
    lli m=0;
    for(int i=0;i<position.size();i++)
        m=(m+power(2,position[i]))%1000000007;
    lli answer=0;
    lli l=n.length();

// part1
// the following is finding summation via loop
    for(int i=1;i<=k;i++)
        answer=(answer + (power(2,l*(k-i))*m)%1000000007)%1000000007;
    cout<<answer<<endl;

//part2
// the following finds the sum by using gp formula (1st_term*(ratio^no_of_terms-1)/(ratio-1))    
    answer=1;
    answer=((power(power(2,l),k) - 1)/(power(2,l)-1))%1000000007;
    answer*=m%1000000007;
    cout<<answer<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Couple of sample inputs and outputs

Input1:

> 4555000 
>   3

Output1:

> 2080638 
>   2080638

Input2:

> 4555000
>   8

Output2:

> 907276560
>   529323732

Edit:- I have figured out the problem. Modulo over division is not defined. The power function returns power modulo K where K=1000000007. Let us call this new value the reduced value. I am dividing two reduced values. Hence, the final answer is also less than the actual answer. Now that I've identified he problem, I still do not know how to overcome this.

Edit2:- Changing the second part to the following works (found it online). I have no idea why.

```
answer=(power(power(2,l),k) - 1);
answer=(answer*power((power(2,l)-1),K-2))%K;
answer=(answer*m)%K;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

interesting; thanks for the question and posting the fix.  fyi, here's the explanation of what you're doing:

you can probably see that you've replace division by x (ie multiplication by 1/x) with multiplication by x^(K-2).  so the question is: why K-2?

and the answer is basically [fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) which says that when you're doing multiplication modulo a prime K (and 100000007 is a prime) then x^(K-1) = 1.  if you divide both sides of that by x then you get x^(K-2) = 1/x.

and i hope you can see how that explains why your code works - on one side you have your K-2, on the other division by x.  so raising to the power K-2 is equivalent, modulo K, to taking the reciprocal.

for example, consider working modulo 5 (which is prime) and dividing 9 by 3.

9/3 = 3 and 3%5 = 3  which is what we want, but division can be a problem:

(9%5)/3 = 4/3 = ?  what does this mean modulo 5? (this was your bug)

so let's used the K-2 trick: 9*(3^(5-2)) = 9*(3^3) = 9*27 = 243 and 243%5 = 3

alternatively, (9%5) * (3^(5-2)) = 4*(3^3) = 4*27 = 108 and 108%5 = 3

Answer (score 2):

In your `long long int` expressions you need to make sure that your literal constants are also `long long int` (currently you are using `int` for literal constants). So for example change:

```
    base=(base*base)%1000000007;
```

to:

```
    base=(base*base)%1000000007LL;
```

---

Better still, you should not litter your code with hard-coded constants, but instead just define a single constant and use that, e.g.

```
const long long int K = 1000000007LL;

....

base=(base*base)%K;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. :) However, the problem still remains. Here's the new version which still gives the same outputs:- http://ideone.com/SNQSCH

Comment: Also, had that been the problem, I believe it should have given wrong answer in both parts.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo operator % precedes *= operator

Comment: Thanks for the info. The problem remains though. Here's the updated version http://ideone.com/SNQSCH